# Jquery: On SlideToggle change text of parent element?

Tags: jquery, html

I am doing slideToggle as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
        $("#show_morecats").click(function(){
        $("#morecats").slideToggle("slow");
        $("#show_morecats").css("background-color","#399C05");
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="show_morecats">More</a>
<div id="morecats" style="display:none;">Some text</div>
```

Now I want when I click `More` link then `morecats` div will open with a slide effect and the color of `more` link will be red and when again click on `more` link then it will be closed and color of link will be blue.

SlideToggle is working quite fine, but coloring of link is not working correctly. I dont want to put :visible condition, because I know there is a function in jquery which does the same, toggle your div and same time will toggle the class or css of the main element, but what that exact function and how to use it. I googled about it but didn't get anything.

Can anyone please suggest me the shortest way to solve this toggling problem.

Comment: Shouldn't I have the accepted answer? I provided an identical solution 15 minutes before the one you marked as accepted..

Comment: @Will: Yes but second one is more clear than your answer, both have the same thing but @Sanders answer is more clear, but I feel you deserve the +1, so that's for you from my side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best way to accomplish the color change when opened and then back to blue when closed, is with a custom class...  this way you can toggle the class...

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#show_morecats').bind('click', function(){
        $('#morecats').slideToggle('slow', function() { 
            $('#show_morecats').toggleClass("opened");
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<a href="#" id="show_morecats">More</a> 
<div id="morecats" style="display:none;">Some text</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#show_morecats { color: blue; }
#show_morecats.opened { color: red; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is you want to change the background colour once the animation has completed? That's what the callback argument is for in slideToggle.

Change the second line to:

```
$('#morecats').slideToggle('slow',
    function() { $('#show_morecats').css({ backgroundColor: '#399C05' });
});
```

You can also use the `toggleClass()` method, though the way you've phrased your question is a little confusing, if I'm honest.